Loop through rows in Excel to pick information to send Outlook emails runs into error on the second row
Sub email_Advice()

    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim rngTo As Range
    Dim rngSubject As Range
    Dim rngRef As Range
    Dim rngBody As Range
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    
    ID = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName

    Range("V8").Select
    XX = ActiveCell.Row
    
Next_Ref:
    If Range("V" & XX).Value = "" Then
        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" Then
        
        Set objOutlook = Nothing
        Set objMail = Nothing
        Set rngTo = Nothing
        Set rngSubject = Nothing
        Set rngBody = Nothing
        
        Exit Sub
        Else
        MsgBox ("Click to generate for next vendor")
        With ActiveSheet
            Set rngTo = .Range("M" & XX)
            Set rngSubject = .Range("O" & XX)
            Set rngBody = .Range("P" & XX)
            Set rngRef = .Range("T" & XX)
        End With
        
        With objMail
         .To = rngTo.Value
         .Subject = rngSubject.Value
         .Body = rngBody.Value
         .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\" & ID & "\Desktop\WHT \" & rngRef & ".pdf"
            .Send
        End With
        
        ActiveCell.Value = "YES"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        XX = XX + 1
        GoTo Next_Ref
        End If
    Else
    
    Exit Sub
    End If
    
End Sub

I executed the code above expecting it to loop through each row, picking the necessary information to send an email, until a blank cell is reached.
The code encounters an error on the second row:

Run time error
The item has been moved or deleted


What line throws the error? It might be a good idea to create a loop instead of using GoTo. Side note: In general, you want to avoid using selectin your code. The active cell is not always the one you think it is.

"\Desktop\WHT \" - Is the space in that path correct ?

The error occurs when execution reaches the line ".To = rngTo.Value" withing the With...End With section of the code

The file path is correct. The code is able to correctly add and send the mail for the first row but always encounters the error on the 2nd row

What is the value in rngTo at that point? Have you tried stepping through the code or using debug.print to see?

I don't usually use VBA with Outlook, but don't you need to create a new mail object for every e-mail you send? Try putting Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0) inside the loop

Untested
Option Explicit

Sub email_Advice()
    Dim objOutlook As Object, objMail As Object
    Dim ID As String, FOLDER as String
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, n As Long
    
    ID = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
    FOLDER = "C:\Users\" & ID & "\Desktop\WHT \"
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 8 To lastrow
            If .Cells(r, "V") = "" Then
                If vbYes = MsgBox("Generate for vendor " & .Cells(r, "M"), vbYesNo) Then
                    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
                    With objMail
                        .To = .Cells(r, "M")
                        .Subject = .Cells(r, "O")
                        .Body = .Cells(r, "P")
                        .Attachments.Add FOLDER & .Cells(r, "T") & ".pdf"
                        .Send
                    End With
                    .Cells(r, "V") = "YES"
                    n = n + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing
    
    MsgBox n & " emails sent", vbInformation

End Sub

